# Meaning of "every point of continuity of an absolutely continuous distribution is a Tjur point"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions

While reading ["On computability and disintegration"](http://math.mit.edu/~freer/papers/AFR-Tjur.pdf) by N. Ackerman, C. Freer, D. Roy, I encountered the following statement (page 7):

> "every point of continuity of an absolutely continuous distribution is a Tjur point"

that I do not know how to interpret. While I am accustomed to the measure-theoretic jargon, it seems that the above uses some terminology from statistics, a field that I have absolutely no idea of.

> Could somebody fluent in both measure theory and statistics translate the above in measure-theoretic terms, please?

In particular, does "point of continuity" mean a point of measure $0$? And what is an "absolutely continuous distribution"? I only know of absolutely continuous measure with respect to another measure, in the context of the Radon-Nikodym theorem, but it seems that the expression has a different use here.

Comment: I interpret it as "a point at which the probability density function is continuous". As for "Tjur point", this *must* be defined in the paper. (BTW, an "absolutely continuous distribution" is a probability measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and so admits a "probability density function", which is the probability jargon for the Radon-Nikodym derivative).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I am only interested in this part of the statement: *"point of continuity of an absolutely continuous distribution"*. Since I am about to base my work on it, I need to be sure of its meaning.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The problem is that in the given context there is no Lebesgue measure (and no other measure, in fact).

Comment: The statement refers to probability measures on $\mathbb R^n$, according to me. After all, it is just an example and it looks like the author considers it to be rather marginal. But this is only my interpretation